# De-interlace captured video with DirectShow

Tags: c++, webcam, directshow, video-capture, interlacing

(Add `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_SCANMODE` into `KSPROPERTY_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL`?)

Working with a webcam I'm getting an interlaced video. The access to that webcam is done with a DirectShow using videoInput library (as part of OpenCV).

I cannot find a way to control that (interlaced) mode with the currently available options/enums in the OpenCV so I diged into MSDN and found the following:

- `IAMCameraControl` interface can be used to get/set various properties, as long as they are listed in `PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389145(v=vs.85).aspx#methods)
- `PROPSETID_VIDCAP_CAMERACONTROL` lists 3 blocks of enums (one for "prior to USB video class, one for UVC, and one for Win8) and among those values there's the one I'm interested in! It's a `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_SCANMODE` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567802(v=vs.85).aspx)
- I have Windows 7.a SDK installed and in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\strmif.h` file what I see is a list of values that only covers the "original" set, which is **pre-UVC**, so it doesn't have the control for the interlaced mode. The enum in that file looks like this one from MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318253(v=vs.85).aspx
- Then I've found this forum where the person claims "I had to update the CameraControlProperty enumeration" to add the needed properties and it worked for him (http://sourceforge.net/p/directshownet/discussion/460697/thread/562ef6cf/)

My question is:
**How**? :) What does one do to add a needed value (or a bunch of values) that are supposedly supported by the system? What am I missing?

MSDN seems to be holding the cards close to its body and not revealing much, so I'm asking the good people in here for help.

I hope someone out there has figured out how to do that and can share the wisdom.

My ultimate goal is to use the OpenCV's videoInput's `setVideoSettingCamera()` to control the interlacing (so that the image I get doesn't have those black lines)

Comment: You can use a directshow deinterlacer to make the video progressive. For example ffdshow. Some inputs only support interlaced video.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however my very specific question was "how" ;-) There are (most likely) many ways to do it. And (in theory) I know *of* them. What I'd like to know is exactly what I asked - *how* do I do that?